# Parent Array Key from array value

Tags: php, arrays

What's the best method to return the corresponding array name (stone, kilogram, pound) from knowing just the acronym value (st, kg, lb)?

```
        "weight" => [

            "stone" => [
                "acronym" => "st"
            ],
            "kilogram" => [
                "acronym" => "kg"
            ],
            "pound" => [
                "acronym" => "lb"
            ]

        ];
```

Comment: Iterate array searching for your acronym.

Comment: I've tried array_search('kg', array_keys($weightArray)); but array_keys() returns the first tier of keys. 0 => stone, 1 => kilogram etc. I'm trying to get 'kilogram' from kg.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function name($array,$t){
    foreach($array as $k=>$a){
       if($a['acronym']===$t){return $k;}
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

A bit lengthy:

```
foreach($mainArray['weight'] as $key=>$value) {
  if(is_array($value)) {
    if(in_array($acronymValue, $value)) {
     echo $key. "has the acronym value";
     break;
  }
  }
}
```

Here is its working demo : [Fiddle](http://phpfiddle.org/main/code/aeh-iub)

Comment: That would give you a false positive for kilograms, if `$mainArray['weight']['stone']['something'] = 'kg'`

Answer (score 0):

You can use `strtr();` (if its ok to change your array)

```
$converter = array(
   'st' => 'stone',
   'kg' => 'kilogram',
   'lb' => 'pound',
);

echo strtr('st', $converter); // stone
```

Answer (score 0):

While question is already answered, Still I think to add a loop-less version using callback anonymous function.

```
function getData($arr, $needle)
{
    $f = array_filter($arr['weight'], function($v) use ($needle) {
        if($v["acronym"] == $needle){
            return $v;
        }
    } );
    list($k, $v) = each($f);

    return $k;

}

echo getData($arr, "kg");
```